# How to find state transitions in a numpy array, from one element to the next?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I would like to identify state transitions in a data set. An example is: "At which index does the sin(x) fall below 0.5?"

The only way I could think of is like this:

```
a = np.arange(0,10,.01)
b= np.sin(a)
c = np.roll(b,1)
c[:1] = 0
print(a[(.5 > b) & (.5< c)])
[2.62 8.91]
```

Can I do that without an additional array c? How can I detect cases like "At which index does sin(x) fall below 0.5 and stay there for 7 samples?" Would i need 7 additional arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 7 steps, you can just build an intermediate array:

```
mask = (b < 0.5)
window = 7

# count the number of times the value is below thresh in the window
below_thresh = np.sum([mask[i:len(mask)-window+i] for i in range(window)], axis=0)

mask1 = below_thresh == window

a[window + 1:][mask1[1:] & (~mask1[:-1])]
# out 
# array([2.62, 8.91])
```

For higher number of steps, you can build the `below_thresh` faster with `as_strided`.

Comment: genius! ... and how do I get the respective indices?

Comment: the first mask and the second are independent from each other, right?

Comment: The indices are where `mask[1:] & (~mask[:-1])` is `True` and shifted by `window + 1`. So something `np.where(mask[1:] & (~mask[:-1])) + window + 1`?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei yes, just reuse the same variable to save some memory. See updates.